# How to query a single key and an array of keys simultaneously in CouchDB?

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I have the following document structure:

```
{
  "_id": "123abc",
  "type": "file",
  "path": ["folder", "subfolder"],
  "filename": "Car.jpg"
}
```

My view looks like this:

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.type=='file') {
    emit([doc.filename, doc.path], null);  
  }
}
```

When I try to query via this URL, I get the following result:

`...?include_docs=true&key=["Car.jpg"]&keys=["folder", "subfolder"]`

> error "query_parse_error"
>
> reason    "`keys` is incompatible with `key`, `start_key` and `end_key`"

If it is not compatible originally how would you then try to achieve such a query?

Comment: Are you trying to get the document with the doc.filename == "Car.jpg" AND doc.path = ["folder", "subfolder"] ?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the "key" parameter when you want to get a document with a specific key.

If you want to query multiple specific documents, you need to use the keys parameters (you pass an array of keys)

In your case,  the view emits the following key:

> [a_file_name, an_array_of_folder]

So if you want to get the document with the filename="Car.jpg" AND doc.path = ["folder","subfolder"], you need to use the following parameters:

> ?key=["Car.jpg",["folder","subfolder"]]

Comment: Ah okay, I see. This was the mistake with my thinking. I'm glad for your advice.